# What dimensions should a brew bag be for 5 gallon batches?

Tags: biab

I began brewing BIAB with a starter kit for 1 gallon batches. I would like to move up to 5 gallon batches, but my original brew bag would be too small for the quantity of grains required.

I know nothing of "needlework", I can buy material and give it to someone who would make it for me, but i need to buy the correct amount/dimensions of material.

What amount of material would I need to buy and what would the pattern dimensions be to make the actual bag?

Comment: I think this will depend entirely on the dimensions of your brewing kettle.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs, that is probably the best place to start. I do not have my pot yet but wanted to start with the bag and was hoping there would be "general" sizes to work with. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [5 gallon paint straining bags](http://www.fleetfarm.com/detail/trimaco-supertuff-elastic-top-strainers/0000000014632) for 5 gallon BIAB.  My suggestion is to buy a two pack (that's how they're sold) and use one as a sizing pattern.